# EJS File not executing JS Module scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, ejs

I have a ejs file which runs on localhost. I want to execute functions from other files imported with js. In my ejs file I have a module script tag and it does execute the code of the file with is in the src of the module script tag aslong as it has no imports. So when i just have a console.log in my js file it executes but as soon as i add an import it does not do anything at all.

This is my app.js file

```
// Requirements
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: `.env.development` });


require("./src/dataBase/dbConfig.js")

const corsOptions = { origin: process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN };

const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//template engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "src/views"));

// response handler middleware
app.use(require("./src/utils/response"));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "src/views")));


app.use(require('./src/routes'));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "developing") {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(` | Server running | http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/`);
  });
} else {
  module.exports = app;
}
```

This is my index.ejs file inside of src/views

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type="module" src="./src//js/handers/fileHandler/loadFiles//loadJs.js"defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="./src//js/handers/fileHandler/loadFIles/loadCss.js"defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="./src//js/handers/fileHandler/fileHandler.js"defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="./src/js/index.js" defer></script>

</head>
<body>
   <div class="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my index.js file inside of src/views/src/js

```
console.log("test")

import { loadFiles } from "./handlers/filehandler/fileHandler.js";

loadFiles()
```

THat test is never logged.

Answer (score 0):

`import` its the "new" way to import js files in ES6 (its called ES modules). You have to add in your package.json `"type": "module",` so node will use ES modules which means you will be able to use `import` stament as you want.

If you finally change the import way to ES modules, you have to also replace all `require` staments with `import` ones.

Check this [article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/ecmascript-modules-nodejs/) to get in touch with ES modules.